# How to always get the latest code of a project

Tags: java, jenkins, github

I've been working on a jar in eclipse on my PC and wanted to be able to access it on another laptop, the jar has a dependency of another jar that I'm working on and both are live projects that I'm always updating.

To do this I followed a tutorial and got both my projects (which are pushed to GitHub every night when i finish the changes for the day) and installed Jenkins on a Raspberry Pi and created a job for the projects. Then I imported the project into IntelliJ from GitHub, but my question is how do I make the main project always have the latest version and how do I get the other project to always have the latest of itself and the one it depends on?

I've tried searching online but don't know what to search exactly.

Comment: What does your jenkins server do?

Comment: right now nothing, I just created the job and now I'm stuck. I don't know exactly what this is called to research it either :(

Comment: I was asking because Jenkins is usually used for CI (continuous integration), which means you can add a pipeline to your jenkins server to publish your jars to a maven repository. There are also ways to [use github as a maven repo](https://gist.github.com/fernandezpablo85/03cf8b0cd2e7d8527063) which might be a more compelling option since you already use github

Comment: @smac89 The reason I couldn't use GitHub was it wouldn't allow me to always get the latest build for a private repo without paying for a service, so i setup my own on jenkins

Comment: There is a way to still use a private github repo as a maven repo, you just need a [token](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5571) and this method requires using gradle and a bit more complex. Alternatively since you have a raspberry pi, you can setup a simple maven repo on a server on the device and have your projects pull the latest versions from there.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: In general, you need to setup a dependency management system for your project (gradle or maven are fine choices for java), then you need to have a way to publish snapshots of your projects and then consume the artifacts after they are published

Comment: Well this is the part where you now have to do some research. Since your project is private, you already have a limitation there unless you opt to use some in-house options (like the pi you mentioned). Otherwise there are free online repos you can try like jfrog, you will also need a dependency management like maven, or gradle. At the end of the day, your goal is to download files, so any old file server will do.

Comment: If you decide on using maven then this [Apache tutorial, "Maven in 5 Minutes"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html),might help out.